# Need to create Facebook events feed from public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I'm trying to get an events feed from a Public Facebook page, but can't get it working.

- I've an app with "Page Public Content Access" permission.
- I try `{page-id}/events` and `{page-id}/feed` without luck. In the first case I get an empty data array, in the second one I get all posts but no events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot get events from public pages anymore (this had been changed after Cambridge Analytica).